# ActiveMQ "Classic" to ActiveMQ Artemis migration / HTTP transport configuration (consume and produce messages using HTTP tunneling)

Tags: java, http, activemq-artemis, broker

I'm having a problem to connect to Artemis using HTTP instead of TCP.

So I have on my ActiveMQ "Classic" a configuration to connect to the broker using HTTP just like that:

```xml
<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?transport.maximumConnections=1000&amp;transport.wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600&amp;transport.keepAlive=true&amp;transport.trace=true&amp;transport.useKeepAlive=true&amp;transport.connectionTimeout=30000" />
    <transportConnector name="http" uri="http://0.0.0.0:9090?transport.maximumConnections=1000&amp;transport.wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600&amp;transport.keepAlive=true&amp;transport.trace=true&amp;transport.useKeepAlive=true&amp;transport.connectionTimeout=30000" />
</transportConnectors>
```

With this configuration I was able to connect to my ActiveMQ using e.g. `http://localhost:9090`.

Now I am migrating to Artemis version 2.28.0, and when I try to configure an http connector like that:

```xml
<connectors>
   <connector name="http-connector">http://0.0.0.0:8080?httpEnabled=true</connector>
</connectors>
```

But when we start up the broker we have the error that the schema is not found:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Schema http not found
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.ConfigurationUtils.parseConnectorURI(ConfigurationUtils.java:190)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.deployers.impl.FileConfigurationParser.parseConnectorTransportConfiguration(FileConfigurationParser.java:1622)
```

We also tried configuration it using `tcp` connections with `httpEnabled=true` according to [Artemis documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/configuring-transports.html#configuring-netty-http) (see "Configuring Netty HTTP"), but this also does not wrong when we try to connect using HTTP.

We have multiple consumers already connected to our ActiveMQ "Classic" via HTTP and we are aiming to do a DNS switch from "Classic" to Artemis without impacting our consumers because would be hard to talk to all of them. This is the scenario: `http://broker:8080` is now pointing to ActiveMQ "Classic" and we want to reroute this domain to point to Artemis.

Comment: You definitely should be using `tcp://0.0.0.0:8080/httpEnabled=true`. You indicated you tried this but had problems, but you didn't elaborate on what those problems were. Can you elaborate on that now? What kind of client are you using?

Comment: @JustinBertram Thanks for the reply, the problem we are facing is that we have clients connecting to our ActiveMQ Classic using `http://` instead of `tcp://` and when we create the configuration with `tcp://0.0.0.0:8080/httpEnabled=true` on artemis and try to connect to the broker using `http://0.0.0.0:8080` the connection keeps hanging and we don't have a response from the broker. i am trying to get more logs information to add here too!

Comment: @JustinBertram we are trying to connect using Apache camel with a java spring-boot application the same way as we use to do in activemq classic, but we also tried to curl the endpoint with `http://0.0.0.0:8080` and we do not have a response from the broker.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use an OpenWire JMS client with HTTP to connect to the acceptor on the broker configured with `httpEnabled=true`. That won't work. You'd need to use the core JMS client library in your applications. Is there a specific reason you are using HTTP?

Comment: Hi @JustinBertram we have multiple consumers already connected to our activemq classic via HTTP and we are aiming to do a DNS switch from classic to Artemis without impacting our consumers because would be hard to talk to all of them. this is the scenario: `http://broker:8080` is now pointing to activemq classic, we wanted to reroute this domain to point to artemis

Comment: Hi @JustinBertram, to clarify which artifact do you mean with „core jms client library“ In Artemis Docu / The Client Classpath I can see artemis-core-client (missing ‘jms’) and artemis-jms-client (missing ‘core’)

Comment: `artemis-jms-client` implements the JMS API, but it depends on `artemis-core-client` for the wire protocol, etc. to actually communicate with the broker, hence "core JMS client." To be clear, the JMS specification doesn't define a wire protocol so it's up to the provider to implement however they see fit. ActiveMQ Artemis supports 3 different JMS implmentations (i.e. AMQP, OpenWire, and Core).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this won't be possible as Artemis doesn't support the HTTP transport as used by OpenWire clients. As you discovered in the documentation, Artemis has an equivalent feature for tunneling communication for the core protocol via HTTP, but it isn't compatible with OpenWire.

Generally speaking, HTTP is not a good protocol for messaging and is rarely recommended. It is available as a stop-gap measure for exceptional situations where "normal" connectivity is not possible for whatever reason.